# Anonymous (no ID, no verification) Payments to PayPal?

Tags: privacy, paypal

*Not looking for a discussion on how Bitcoin payments can be traced and it's not **truly** anonymous. I'm not looking for total anonymity, I just don't want the merchant or payment processor to identify me.*

Prior to their update, you could use BitInstant to send money to peoples' PayPal addresses straight from a Bitstamp coupon. Now, they want you to verify who you are with a name, address, urine sample etc. I'm looking for services like the *old* BitInstant which allow you to direct-pay to PayPal.

Tor being allowed is a plus but not required. I can pay from Bitcoin, MtGox, BTC-e or Bitstamp. The minimum transaction should be trivial, no more than $25-30.

Thanks for the help.